Istioctl install command fails because timeout getting minimum supported Kubernetes version
I installed istioctl on my Mac and am trying to run this command from the terminal
istioctl install --set profile=demo -y

However this is the immediate response:
Error: check minimum supported Kubernetes version: error getting Kubernetes version: Get "https://0.0.0.0:52094/version?timeout=5s": dial tcp 0.0.0.0:52094: connect: connection refused

My istioctl version is 1.24.1 and I'm running Kubernetes v1.30.5. Does anyone know why this happens?

I tried to replicate the same configuration as yours and got the same error using minikube when the ~/.kube/config directory is missing. After ensuring that the kubeconfig file is valid and properly configured, installing istioctl worked on my end. Validate and reset the kubeconfig if it is present on your Mac as it is required by kubectl to connect to a Kubernetes cluster.

